# Merging rows in a single table

Tags: sql, merge, rows

I have a table that looks like this:

```
abs0| rel0 | abs1 | rel1
=========================
60  | 0.6  | NULL | NULL 
NULL| NULL |  40  |  0.4
```

and would like for it to look like this:

```
abs0| rel0 | abs1 | rel1
=========================
60  | 0.6  |  40  |  0.4
```

*This problem is solved

Comment: Is `NA` = `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, NA stand for NULL

Comment: @nhdrizzle . . . I took the liberty of removing your "second" question.  If you have an additional question, then ask it as a question.  Your actual question has two correct answers, and it is rude not to accept one of them an move on.

Comment: @nhdrizzle: Kindly read what to do when [someone answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation function  for elide  null eg::

```
select min(abs0) as abs0, min(rel0) as rel0, min(abs1) as abs1, min(rel1) as rel1
from my_table
```

Comment: additional question. Let's say I have a second row of each. So first two rows with values for abs0 and rel0 followed by two rows with values for abs1 and rel1. How do I merge those, if I want my final table to have the values of the first and third row together and the values of the second and forth row?

Comment: @nhdrizzle . . . I removed your edit.  Ask an additional question as a *new* question.

Comment: @nhdrizzle  change a question after you have obtained  a valid answer  is not fair  .. so if my answer respect to  your original question is right  you  should mark my answer  as  accepted ..   and if you need  post a new question  .. eventually you can comment me the link to new question  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max`.

```
SELECT max(c1) AS c1
    ,max(c2) AS c2
    ,max(c3) AS c3
    ,max(c4) AS c4
FROM t1;
```

**Result:**

```
C1   C2     C3   C4
--------------------
60   0.60   40   0.40
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/UTOV88827)

Comment: Thanks. Works! I have edited my post because a new question to this topic has come to light. I'd be grateful if you could check it out!

Comment: @nhdrizzle: Kindly ask new question as suggested by Gordon. Thanks!